# OpsHub TFS to VSO Migration Unable to connect to server. OH-CONFIG-0059

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

I'm trying to migrate from TFS2013 to VSO using the OpsHub Migration tool. The tool is installed on my TFS machine. I'm able to use a browser to see VSO, run the tool, select my TFS and VSO, select my Team Projects, map my users, but when it tries to validate the migration I get the following error after a couple of minutes.

> Validation failed due to following reason(s), try to validate again
>   after making the following changes.
>   com.opshub.eai.config.exception.ConfigServiceException:
>   OH-CONFIG-0059: Validation Failed. Unable to connect to server
>   https://mysubdomain.visualstudio.com/ at this moment. Please try again.

The log from

```
C:\Program Files\OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility\logs\OpsHubTFSService.log
```

> 2015-10-17 13:11:15,991 [5] DEBUG Connecting to the team foundation server instance http://mytfsserver/tfs/
>   2015-10-17 13:11:16,018 [5] DEBUG Login successful for token xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
>   2015-10-17 13:11:16,029 [5] DEBUG Connecting to the team foundation server instance https://mysubdomain.visualstudio.com/
>   2015-10-17 13:11:19,838 [5] DEBUG Login successful for token yyyyyyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyyyyyyyyyy
>   2015-10-17 13:16:49,546 [5] ERROR Error : The operation has timed out    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpWebRequest.SendRequestAndGetResponse(HttpWebRequest webRequest, WebException& webException)

I've tried numerous times over a wide timespan and can browse directly to the VSO site in a browser.

To the best of knowledge, there is no firewall restriction that would stop outbound communication like this. Does the tool use a custom port?

Does anyone have more details about this exception and how to solve it?

Comment: Hi, The utility uses ports 8989 and 9090. Can you try after increasing the timeout values in opshubtfsservice.exe.config @ C:\Program Files\OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility\Other_Resources\Resources\TFSUtility\TFSService and then in ovsmu.exe.config @ C:\Program Files\OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility\Other_Resources\Resources\TFSUtility. (Search for the work timout in the file)

Comment: I will try and let you know how it goes. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, Were you able to resolve the issue? If not then please contact support@opshub.com with logs from C:\Program Files\OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility\logs. You can send the zipped logs folder.

Comment: Hi Greg, any update on it ?

Comment: Not yet. I haven't had a time frame open yet.

Comment: I was able to get a time frame and try out your suggestion, but there was a mandatory update of your tool to version 2. After updating, I tried without altering the configs and it worked as expected. The decision to force everyone to v2 and also disable multi-project migrations in the process is a major pain point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to upgrade to version 2 of the OpsHub utility. They have disabled all previous versions.

Comment: The change in version 2 forcing each Team Project to be done in a new migration makes using this tool extremely time consuming. The lookup for Team Projects and User Mappings each take several minutes. Then the configuration for the migration takes several minutes.